# Handling WebView file download and runtime permissions

Tags: android, webview, download

When I click on a button in the `WebView`, it should download a PDF file which will be saved to external storage.

For that, I'm setting a `DownloadListener`:

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadHandler());

public class DownloadHandler implements DownloadListener {

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(url));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getFileName(url));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

The problem arises when trying to do that on Android M, where all permissions are asked on runtime.

How should I ask for permission first before launching the download, and continue or not with the download depending if they were granted?

The download URL calls `shouldInterceptRequest` not `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, so I'm not even sure how could I cancel the request to check for permissions first.

Asking for permissions once the `WebView` launches isn't an option because you can do a lot more than just downloading files.

Comment: Check the permission, call `requestPermissions()` if you do not have it, and the kick off the download in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` if the user then granted permission.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly where I'm lost. I understand that's the logic to follow, but I don't know where to check the permissions (shouldInterceptRequest? onDownloadStart?), how to cancel the request, and how to create a new one once the user has granted the permission.

Comment: Well, I have never implemented this. I would try calling `checkSelfPermission()` and, if needed, `requestPermissions()` in `onDownloadStart()`. AFAIK, there is no "cancel the request" semantics here, as `WebView` is delegating the work to you, and it is up to you to decide how to do it. So, if you want to postpone the work until an `onRequestPermissionsResult()` call, I see no reason why `WebView` would have grounds for complaint. In terms of "create a new one", all you are using is `url`, so stuff that in a field on your activity or fragment (wherever you are requesting the permissions).

Comment: Now, it is entirely possible that there are hiccups in my plan, as there often are (a side effect of being a Murphy and having a Law to contend with). But, that is what I would try, and if you run into specific problems, fire off a fresh Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] and details of those problem.

Comment: @RominaV if you could please post your solution